# Stylesheet stopped showing my changes - django

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm working on a new site and made a quick css stylesheet just to give my templates some structure.  I edited the stylesheet no problem.

I finished up some backend code and decided to go back and work on my stylesheet some more.  But when I make changes to the stylesheet, none of those changes are reflected on my webpage when I reload the page, instead it continues to show my old styles.   They seem to be stuck at a point in time and don't change no matter what I do to the stylesheet code.

Here's the relevant code:

**Stylesheet - css/screen.css:**

```
#main-banner {
    background-color:#DC3211;
    color:white;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}

#main-banner-text   {
    font-size:35px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px black;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#main-banner a:link, #main-banner a:visited {
    font-size: 14px;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:underline;
}


/* Navigation */
div.menu    {
    height:10px;
    background-color:49443A;
    font-size:16px !important;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

div.menu    ul  li  a   {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}
div.menu    ul  li  a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:white;
}

div.menu    ul  li  {
    display:inline;
    padding-top:15px;
    margin-left:18px;
}

.header-title {
    font-size:16px;
}

input.required, select.required {
    background-color: #FFDDDD;
}
```

**Header in my template:**

```
<head>
        <title>YourPoolHub.com</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/blueprint/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/blueprint/lib/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
    </head>
```

**Things I've tried**

-Clearing the cache in the browser.

-Removing all of the code from the stylesheet just to see what would happen but it still displays the same styles from the style sheet.

-When I remove this line in the template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

The styles in css/screen.css go away, but again, if I kept that line and removed the code from the stylesheet the old styles would still show.

I hope I'm just over looking something.  Any help would be appreciated.

oh and I have in my settings:

STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Anthony/Desktop/NewSite/mysite/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured out what was happening.

When I went to update my style sheet I was going to the static root directory.

What I didn't realize was that I had a static folder in one of my apps and when I ran collectstatic it copied that screen.css file into the static root directory.

So instead of updating the original screen.css file I was updating the copy in the static root.

Comment: Nice! Go ahead and accept your own answer in order to mark the question as resolved. (Also it's good to set your editor so that it ignores the folder with generated files.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have DEBUG and TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False? If so, you might need to run ./manage.py collectstatic to gather your changed static files and send them to your static root.

If this is happening with DEBUG = True, then this won't solve your problem.

Comment: They are both set to True

Comment: Did you change any of the STATIC settings between the time you first created the stylesheet and now? I wonder if it's loading the static files from a different directory. 

Also, could you post your directories? Could be helpful.

Comment: That's exactly what it was doing.  I had a static folder in one of my apps that it was reading from.  I figured it out earlier but I wasn't allowed to post an answer to my own question until 8 hours after posting it.